# devise Rails 5 security extension error using update_with_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

There seems to be a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33916385/devise-rails-5-branch-using-update-with-password-not-generated-expected-passwo), but no one was able to answer it. It also seems to be a bit different.

I am upgrading from rails 4.2.4 to Rails 5.0.0.1.
When I try to run a password expiration after 30 days, it goes through the update action where the problem occurs on the second line:

```
def update
  resource.extend(Devise::Models::DatabaseAuthenticatablePatch)
  if resource.update_with_password(resource_params)
    warden.session(scope)['password_expired'] = false
    set_flash_message :notice, :updated
    sign_in scope, resource, :bypass => true
    redirect_to stored_location_for(scope) || :root
  else
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    respond_with(resource, action: :show)
  end
end
```

And here is that module that gets ran:

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module DatabaseAuthenticatablePatch
      def update_with_password(params, *options)

        new_password = params[:password]
        new_password_confirmation = params[:password_confirmation]

        result = if new_password.present? && new_password_confirmation.present?
                   update_attributes(params, *options)
                 else
                   self.assign_attributes(params, *options)
                   self.valid?
                   self.errors.add(:password, new_password.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
                   self.errors.add(:password_confirmation, new_password_confirmation.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
                   false
                 end

        clean_up_passwords
        result
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The error happens when you hit `update_attributes(params, *options)`

Then i get this error.

```
undefined method `<<' for #<OldPassword::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007ffe59a0ffa0>
```

If anyone could help me figure this one out, that would be amazing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was devise_security_extension gem.
I am using password_archivable and in their module, I needed to convert the old_password object into an array to be able to add the changing password to the table.

I ended up creating a password_archivable.rb and putting it in the initializers.

```
module Devise
  module Models
    # PasswordArchivable
    module PasswordArchivable
      # validate is the password used in the past
      def password_archive_included?
        unless self.class.deny_old_passwords.is_a? Fixnum
          if self.class.deny_old_passwords.is_a? TrueClass and archive_count > 0
            self.class.deny_old_passwords = archive_count
          else
            self.class.deny_old_passwords = 0
          end
        end
        if self.class.deny_old_passwords > 0 and not self.password.nil?
          old_passwords_including_cur_change = self.old_passwords.order(:id).reverse_order.limit(self.class.deny_old_passwords).to_a
          old_passwords_including_cur_change << OldPassword.new(old_password_params)  # include most recent change in list, but don't save it yet!
          old_passwords_including_cur_change.each do |old_password|
            dummy                    = self.class.new
            dummy.encrypted_password = old_password.encrypted_password
            dummy.password_salt      = old_password.password_salt if dummy.respond_to?(:password_salt)
            return true if dummy.valid_password?(self.password)
          end
        end
        false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That was the only problem.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Great solution. Thank you very much. Helps a lot.